Limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(e^x-1)^2-x\ln(x+1)}{\tan(x) - x}$
I'm trying to calculate the following limit using Taylor's polynomial:
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(e^x-1)^2-x\ln(x+1)}{\tan(x) - x}$
I expanded the exponent part up to a third degree polynomial, the logarithm to fourth degree polynomial, and the $\tan (x) $ to a third degree polynomial (all around $x_0 = 0 $ ).
I have also tried other degrees in the numerator, and the denominator, aiming that the higher degree of $x$ will be in the numerator. However I am constantly ending up having at least one $x$ in the numerator with degree 2 or less.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!
Additionally, if you have any suggestions on making intelligent "guesses" about the order of the polynomials I should expand when using this method of calculating limits, I would very much like to hear them.
Thank you!

The numerator behaves like $3x^3/2.$ The denominator like $x^3/3.$ Do the limit is $9/2.$

I wouldn't jump up to fourth degree right away, expanding the numerator to second degree and the denominator to third degree should work.  I would just start with a few terms and add more if you need to.

It's a bit hard to judge where your attempt is going wrong without including the actual work.

I guess you made some calculus mistake at some point. To try to guess the degree I had to develop, I took a look at the denominator with the $\tan(x)-x \approx \frac{x^3}{3}$ and so tried degree $3$ at first:
$$(e^x-1)^2 = \left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\right)^2=x^2+2\frac{x^3}{2}+o(x^3)$$
$$x\ln(1+x) = x\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\right)=x^2-\frac{x^3}{2}+o(x^3)$$
So for the whole numerator : $$(e^x-1)^2-x\ln(1+x) = x^2+x^3-x^2+\frac{x^3}{2}+o(x^3) \approx \frac{3}{2}x^3$$
Finally, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(e^x-1)^2-x\ln(1+x)}{\tan(x)-x}\approx\frac{\frac{3}{2}x^3}{\frac{1}{3}x^3}\approx \frac{9}{2}$$
Hope it helps!

Clem105, there is a mistake in your answer, indeed you wrote $$x\ln(1+x)=x\left(x-\frac x2+o(x^2)\right)=x^2-\frac{x^3}2$$instead of $$x\ln(1+x)=x\left(x-\frac{\color{red}{x^2}}2+o(x^2)\right)=x^2-\frac{x^3}2\color{red}{+o(x^3)}$$

Yes, my bad, thanks !

I am going to calculate your limit by using the following notables limits:
$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1}x=1\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\color{blue}{(1)}$
$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\dfrac12\qquad\qquad\;\color{blue}{(2)}$
$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}=-\dfrac12\;\qquad\color{blue}{(3)}$
$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3}=\dfrac13\;\qquad\qquad\color{blue}{(4)}$
It results that
$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{(e^x-1)^2-x\ln(x+1)}{\tan(x)-x}=$
$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\frac{(e^x-1)^2-x^2}{x^3}-\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}}{\frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3}}=$
$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\frac{e^x-1+x}x\cdot\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}-\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}}{\frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3}}=$
$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\left(\frac{e^x-1}x+1\right)\cdot\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}-\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}}{\frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\underset{\color{blue}{\overbrace{\text{ by using }(1),(2),(3),(4)}}}{=}$
$=\dfrac{(1+1)\cdot\frac12+\frac12}{\frac13}=\dfrac{1+\frac12}{\frac13}=\dfrac32\!\cdot\!3=\dfrac92\,.$
